# Location of the .view.xml and .controller.js files on SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have created a very simple app on SAPUI but for some reason the .view.xml and the .controller.js files need to be in the same directory than the sap-ui-core.js file, which does not suit me.

When declaring the SAPUI5 bootstrap I specify the directory for that sap-ui-core.js file:

```
<script src="js/sapui/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

So in this case, all the .view.xml files need to be under js/sapui/

Where in the app code can I specify the location of those files? I would like them to be in the same directory than the index.html

```
 var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("getStarted");
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
     oModel.setData(data);
     myView.setModel(oModel);
     myView.placeAt('content');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have a folder called `folder` and inside it the view-controller-pair `foo.view.xml` and `foo.controller.js`

then you can use

```
sap.ui.localResources("folder");
var fooView = sap.ui.xmlview("folder.foo");
fooView.placeAt("someNicePlace");
```

in your case you use

```
sap.ui.localResources("js");
var fooView = sap.ui.xmlview("js.sapui.foo");
fooView.placeAt("someNicePlace");
```

Comment: Thanks herrlock, assuming I have the www folder, and inside that I create an "app" folder, containing the view-controller-pair, could I just do:    sap.ui.localresources("app");  ? or what is that folder relative to?

Comment: That location should be relative to the root of your file, where (normally) the `index.html` is.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use files from a different folder structure, you can use

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('controllers', '/js/controllers/');
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('views', '/js/views/');
```

which loads the files from your desired location, relative to the base path.